# Why is the verb not in the second position in "Lass uns am Sonntagabend einen Spaziergang um den See machen."?

Tags: word-order

Why is the verb not in the second position in "Lass uns am Sonntagabend einen Spaziergang um den See machen."? I don't understand the word order in this sentence. Could someone please explain? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verb is no more in second position than in the simpler "Mach(e) einen Spaziergang um den See". Both are imperatives, and the verb order rule you cite applies to indicative sentences only.

Answer (score 2):

It’s an imperative, so the verb is in first position.

Answer (score 2):

*Lass* is the root form of the Verb lassen (infinitive) and it's used as the imperative here. That's why you just drop out the ending *en*. And because it is imperative, the verb is at the beginning. The verb *machen* is at the end and in its infinitive form, because it is the 2nd verb in the sentence.